# How do you choose the "3D View Full" workspace?

Tags: workspaces

Seriously, it randomly appears on certain files but I have no idea how I made it happen and can't find the answer anywhere online.  I really like using it to explore my scenes and would be really appreciate it if I could find out how to bring it up.  Because it's not an option to add as a workspace for some reason, and it's driving me crazy.  Please help.

Comment: Not sure if you mean Full Screen Viewport, if so : CTRL + ALT + Spacebar

Answer (score 1):

To make your viewport size bigger you can try *CTRL + Space* or *CTRL + ALT + Space*.

**If you want to create a workspace that has a big viewport:**

1. Click the '+' button to the right of the scripting tab(assuming you haven't added or removed workspaces)

[image: Picture of where it is located]

2. In the general section choose 'Layout'

[image: Picture of where it is located]

Optional: You can rename the workspace by double-clicking on the 'Layout.001' tab

3. Start collapsing all the windows except the 3D viewport. This is done by moving your cursor to an intersection of 2 windows so that it changes to a '+' sign, then by dragging towards one of the windows.

[image: Picture of collapsing the outliner]

Do this for all the ones you don't want.